# How to serve different CSS file when user change language in Django i18n translation

Tags: css, django, nginx, internationalization, django-i18n

I am using Django i18n translation system and there are two languages:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('fa', _('Persian')),
    ('en', _('English')),
    )
```

Persian is Right-To-Left and I want to serve another CSS file when user change language to persian.
Or maybe there is a better way to change LTR to RTL when user change the language?

I am using **nginx** with **wsgi** on a **Ubuntu** vps.

Comment: You could add a class to the body specifying which language you are using and change your style accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way:

I assume you have 2 css files for example static/css/fa.css and static/css/en.css

1. In template, when you link your css you can do it like this:

   ```
   <link type="text/css" href="{% trans 'static/css/en.css' %}">
   ```
2. In your Persian translation file you put then something like this:

   ```
   msgid "static/css/en.css"
   msgstr "static/css/fa.css"
   ```

Alternatively, if the only thing you want from css is to change LTR to RTL you could do in your template:

```
{%load i18n%}
{%get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE%}
{%get_language_info for LANGUAGE_CODE as lang%}
....
{% if lang.bidi %}
<!-- Some HTML code for RTL -->
{% else %}
<!-- Some HTML code for LTR -->
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have following file and directory structure:

```
 /static/fa/css/default.css
 /static/en/css/default.css
```

And then I would go with:

```
{% get_static_prefix %}{% get_current_language %}"/css/default.css"
```